Socket authorization does not work in laravel via sanctum
I installed Sanctum, configured authorization, authorization of protected routes via cookies occurs. Everything works for me here, but sockets that work via Pusher do not work.
I completed the setup and configured the client:
https://laravel.su/docs/11.x/sanctum#avtorizaciia-castnyx-kanalov-veshhaniia
I checked that XSRF cookies and the session come to broadcasting/auth, but I still get 401. What could be wrong? Before that, I used token authorization, everything was ok.

Did you try to verify CSRF token before your authentication broadcasting https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#csrf-protection
